# Cannot find restaurant without id, how to submit form and pass parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am attempting to allow a user to create a campaign given they have selected a certain restaurant,
the models are:

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    validates  :user_id, presence: true

    has_many :campaigns, dependent: :destroy
end

class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

That said, I have the methods in the Campaigns controller to create a new campaign and then to build (below).

```
    def new
        if signed_in?
            # create new campaign
            @campaign = Restaurant.find(params[:id]).campaigns.new
        else
            redirect_to signin_path
        end
    end

    def create

        @campaign = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id]).campaigns.build(campaign_params)

        if @campaign.save
            flash[:success] = "Campaign created!"
            redirect_to current_user
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
```

The user progress in the app essentially is: While on the restaurant show page the user clicks on create a campaign, accessing the `new` method in campaign controller. 
The view for a new campaign, without the partial, is below and as can be seen it accepts the `@campaign` from `new`.

```
<h1>New Campaign</h1>

<div class="row"> 
        <div class="span6 offset3">
        <%= nested_form_for @campaign do |f| %>
            <%= render 'parameters', f: f %>
            <div class="span6 pull-right" style="text-align:right">
                <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

As I attempt to submit the form, the error arises with the campaign controllers `create` method at `@campaign = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id]).campaigns.build(campaign_params)` noting `Couldn't find Restaurant without an ID`

As displayed, the campaign belongs to a restaurant with the id in campaign models field :restaurant_id

How can I make this work to pass the restaurants id so the campaign can be created?

Comment: try using `params[:id]` instead of `params[:restaurant_id]`

Comment: I have tried that and it does not work, still lists the same error. Is there some way to pass that specific restaurants id from the `form_for` form into the `create` method once submit is hit?

Comment: well inspect the params and you'll know what's missing

Comment: How do you inspect the parameters? Is there something I can run to view them?

Comment: well there's good gems for that (https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors for example), also you could use breakpoints in debugging mode, something like `debugger` gem, but for a fast thing you could always check the server log ( it lists requests and params passed to each ), or print the object in the views, or maybe render text with the object, like in your example you could add `render text: params.inspect and return` in the first line of the create method.

Comment: But how can I pass the parameters back to the create method after pressing submit. There has to be a standard format for this correct? What is it missing?

Comment: hold on what is the route you're posting to, if you create a nested resource it should work fine, then you'd post to `restaurant/:id/campaign`

Comment: The route is campaign#create

Comment: If you check the HTML code that `<%= render 'parameters', f: f %>` is generating, can you see the `restaurant_id` somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a parameter to a form, use the hidden_field helper just above the submit tag:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :restaurant_id, @campaign.restaurant.id %>
<%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
```

This should be available in the create method of your controller as:

```
params["campaign"]["restaurant_id"]
```

If you for some reason want it to come in simply as params["id"], you would need to use a hidden_field_tag like so:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :id, @campaign.restaurant.id %>
```

Side note - for debugging, you should use the debugging tool called "pry". This will change your life.

Simply add to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'pry'
```

then bundle and restart your server:

```
bundle
rails s
```

Then put a 'binding.pry' anywhere you want (in a view, model, helper, or controller) - the server will pause at the place where you put the binding.pry and you can poke around in the server console.

I would put the binding.pry right inside your create method:

```
def create
  binding.pry
  # rest of code here
end
```

Then submit the form like normal, and check your server screen in the terminal... you should see the Pry prompt.

Type:

```
params
```

to see all of the parameters coming through the form submit.
to exit, type exit or ctrl+c

Remember to remove the binding.pry when you are done!!!